# 1 mouse click out of 2

Tags: mouse, input-devices

I have an intermittent problem with my computer. When I click, only 1 click out of 2 registers so I often have to re-click on something to register a click event. This is obviously very counter productive.

What is strange is that this is an intermittent problem:

- Rebooting has no effect
- Changing batteries has no effect
- It isn't specific to an application, all the OS is affected

Note: When I say 1 mouse click out of 2, it is the most reasonable rate although it isn't consistent. Sometimes I can click more than 1 out of 2 before 1 click doesn't register. I just did 10 clicks in a row that worked in PHPStorm and then I had 3 that wouldn't register. I came back to askubuntu to edit this answer and had 5 more clicks in a row that did not register.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot / fix this issue?

Ubuntu: 16.10
Memory: 7.7Gib
Processor: Intel Core i7-3630QM @ 2.40Ghz x 8
Graphics: Intel Ivybridge Mobile

Comment: Might sound silly but, have you tried different mouse? it might be a hardware issue

Comment: Problem happens at work with different device but same model

Comment: doesn't seem like a hardware issue

Comment: More info, it seems that if i hold down the clicked button for longer (ex: 1 sec) the click always registers